# having trouble overloading << operator within a class and the class's header

Tags: c++, class, io, operator-overloading

so I'm working on a fraction class program, and I'm having a bit of difficulty overloading the output operator. 
the relevant bit of the main file.

```
const fraction fr[] = {fraction(4, 8), fraction(-15,21),
                       fraction(10), fraction(12, -3),
                       fraction(), fraction(28, 6), fraction(0, 12)};

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    cout << "fraction [" << i <<"] = " << fr[i] << endl;
}
```

and in the fraction.h

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const fraction &fr); //the location of the error.
```

and in the class fraction.cpp file

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const fraction& fr)
{
    if(fr.Denominator==1||fr.Numerator==0)
        stream << fr.Numerator;
    else
    stream << fr.Numerator << '/' << fr.Denominator << endl;
    return stream;
}
```

anyway, the error code is straightforward.
‘std::ostream& fraction::operator<<(std::ostream&, const fraction&)’ must take exactly one argument|

I am a bit lost as to why that's what it's telling me. [is it not able to accept functions that take 2 values?, is (std::ostream&, const fraction&) just plain wrong? should it just be a single argument in the parentheses?]

the main function is set in stone and works if my class's cpp and header file are coded correctly as it came with the assignment.

I've only ever done IO overloading in friend functions, never within, and even with those I'm inexperienced, so I'm pretty lost at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you're trying to overload `operator <<` for two arguments, but inside the class operator member functions take only *one* argument (that is, the righthand argument). Your code would work if it were a `friend` of `fraction` because you would be defining a free operator function which takes two arguments.

So to fix, either define the function outside `fraction` or name it as a `friend` of the class. When you name it as a `friend`, the function will be able to access private members of any instance of the class.

Comment: oh I see, I had thought that if I declared a friend function that I had to define the function outside of the class or in this case the .cpp file. thank you. now to get working on the input operator. :D

Comment: You can define `friend` functions both inside and outside the class. If the operator *isn't* a member function of the class (that is, not a class and declared inside in the class) then it has to take its righthand argument as an argument. A global operator function takes both its lefthand argument and its righthand argument. Just trying to be clear. :)